# reactjs peticiones en 2 url distintas php mysql

Tags: php, reactjs, api

Estoy empezando a usar REACT, y quisiera saber como puedo hacer peticiones a VARIAS url.
Otra, de paso. Se puede usar dos componentes? o sea, integrar uno con otro?

Tengo el sigueinte código en react:

```
function AppProductos() {
  const urlProductos="http://localhost/API/productos/";
  const [data, setData]=useState([]);

  const peticionGet=async()=>{
    await axios.get(urlProductos)
    .then(response=>{
      setData(response.data);
    }).catch(error=>{
      console.log(error);
    })
  }

  return(
    <div style={{textAlign: 'center'}}>
      <br/>
      <button className="btn btn-success" onClick={()=>abrirCerrarModalInsertar()}>Insertar</button>
      <br/><br/>
      <Modal isOpen={modalInsertar}>
        <ModalBody>
          <div className="form-group">
            <label>Nombre: </label>
            <br />
            <input type="text" className="form-control" name="nombre" onChange={handleChange}/>
            <br />
            <label>Descripción: </label>
            <br />
            <select name="marca" id="" onChange={handleChange}>
               "ESTE SELECT SE TIENE QUE LLENAR CON LAS MARCAS TRAIDAS DE LA API por URL: http://localhost/API/marcas/"
                
            </select>
            <br />
          </div>
        </ModalBody>
      </Modal>
    </div>
  );
}

export default AppProductos;
```

esto es lo que necesito! como puedo hacer?

DESDE YA MUCHAS GRACIAS!

Comment: ¿Quieres llenar el select con los datos asincronicos de la función `peticionGet`? Y también ¿Quieres crear un componente padre para administrar el estado de los datos y un componente hijo para mostrar el select? Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para hacer las peticiones puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
import React, { useState, /*importante importa useEffect*/ useEffect } from 'react'

function AppProductos() {
  const urlProductos = "http://localhost/API/productos/";
  const urlMarcas = "http://localhost/API/marcas/";
  const [data, setData] = useState({ 'marcas': [], 'productos': [] });

  /** entiendo que de la siguiente manera es que deseas hacer las peticiones **/

  /*const peticionGet=async()=>{
    await axios.get(urlProductos)
    .then(response=>{
      setData(response.data);
    }).catch(error=>{
      console.log(error);
    })
  }*/

  /** pero puedes hacerlas mejor (con axios y async await (es importante aclarar que al haber un error automaticamente javascript detendra la ejecucion y mostrara el problema en consola)) **/
  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      await getProductos()
      await getMarcas()
    })();
  }, [])

  const getProductos = async () => {
    const response = await axios.get(urlProductos).data;
    setData({ ...data, productos: response });
  }

  const getMarcas = async () => {
    const response = await axios.get(urlMarcas).data;
    setData({ ...data, marcas: response });
  }

  return(
    <div style={{textAlign: 'center'}}>
      <br/>
      <button className="btn btn-success" onClick={()=>abrirCerrarModalInsertar()}>Insertar</button>
      <br/><br/>
      <Modal isOpen={modalInsertar}>
        <ModalBody>
          <div className="form-group">
            <label>Nombre: </label>
            <br />
            <input type="text" className="form-control" name="nombre" onChange={handleChange}/>
            <br />
            <label>Descripción: </label>
            <br />
            <select name="marca" id="" onChange={handleChange}>
               {data.marcas.map((item, i) => (
                 <option value={item['campoAGuardar']}>{item['campoAMostrar']}</option>
               ))}                
            </select>
            <br />
          </div>
        </ModalBody>
      </Modal>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Sobre lo de anidar componentes no se a que te refieres pero puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
import React from 'react'
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles'

import {
  Typography,
  Container,
  Link,
} from '@material-ui/core'

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
  }
}));

function AppTitle({ title, url, urlTitle }) {
  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Container maxWidth='md'>
        <Typography
          variant='h3'
          component='p'
          align='center'
          color='primary'
        >
          {title} <Link href={url} target='_blank'>{urlTitle}</Link>
        </Typography>
      </Container>
    </div>
  )
}

export default function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <AppTitle
        title='Te recomiendo muchisimo:'
        url='https://material-ui.com'
        urlTitle='@material-ui'
      />
    </div>
  )
}
```